# what are the various in-app billing options available for both Android and Amazon

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, amazon-appstore

We are building a game which contains some premium goods/levels for which we want to use in-app billing. We are targeting this game for the Amazon app-store as well as for the Google Android Market.

We want to use the same code base for both the markets.

I understand that we cannot use Google's IAB (in-app billing) on Amazon kindle fire because Android Market app will not be available on the Kindle fire. 
Can we use Amazon's in-app billing on Android market distributions?

What are the other various payment options available on both markets? Can we use a generic in-app payment service other than these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RoboBillingLibrary](https://github.com/christopherperry/RoboBillingLibrary) for in app billing if you want to publish across Google Play and the Amazon Appstore. It handles the details for you so you only have one implementation that works for both.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, you can use amazon's IAP only if you download the app from the amazon app-store. In order words, your app has to be setup so that use amazon IAP if it was downloaded via amazon, use google IAP if it was downloaded via the android market. If you want to use the same apk to handle both situation, you need to implements two mechanism.